# How to customize the font size of an active tab in material-ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

My Requirement is such that only the active tab should have a specific color and font-size.

This is my code:

```
                    <Tabs
                        value={value}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        classes={{indicator: classes.customStyleOnActiveTab}}
                        aria-label="some text"
                        >
                        <Tab label={<span className={classes.customStyleOnTab}>Tab 1</span>} />
                        <Tab label={<span className={classes.customStyleOnTab}> Tab 2</span>}/>
                    </Tabs>
```

However, it changes the styling on both the tabs whereas I want only the active tab to have a particular style (blue color and bold font). The other tab should have a normal `font-weight` and `color`:

[image]

If I use `textColor` property, I can achieve the desired result but I wouldn't be able to customize it. I dug into the material doc, and eventually tried all the CSS classes they've exposed, without any luck

Comment: "and eventually tried all the CSS classes they've exposed" - where are you using these CSS classes? Do your new style rules' selectors [have the minimum specificity required to override the existing rules](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)? If nothing else, there's always `!important`.

Comment: @Dai unfortunately `!important` diesnt do the job (say if I try to override, `wrapper` class; it simply throws a warning on console saying you can't override it) since following are the only classes on which I can put my cusom css:
`root,vertical,flexContainer,flexContainerVertical,centered,scroller,fixed,scrollable,scrollButtons,scrollButtonsDesktop,indicator.`

I was trying to override these classes the way I have done for `indicator`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For adding custom/different style to the active tab you can assign a class to the active tab conditionally. Every `Tab` has its own value (which is their index value also) and assign them class conditionally.

Here is the link of codesandbox:- https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-tu-lxi1g?file=/src/App.js

```
    import React, { useState } from "react";
    import "./styles.css";
    import {Tabs, Tab, makeStyles} from '@material-ui/core'

    export default function App() {
      const classes = useStyles()
      const [value, setValue] = useState(0)

      const handleChange = (e, newVal)=>{
        setValue(newVal)
      }


      return (
        <div className="App">
          <Tabs
            value={value}
            onChange={handleChange}
            classes={{indicator: classes.customStyleOnActiveTab}}
            aria-label="some text"
          >
            <Tab label={<span className={ value === 0 ? classes.activeTab : classes.customStyleOnTab}>Tab 1</span>} />
            <Tab label={<span className={ value === 1 ? classes.activeTab : classes.customStyleOnTab}> Tab 2</span>}/>
          </Tabs>
        </div>
      );
    }


    const useStyles = makeStyles({
      customStyleOnTab:{
        fontSize:'15px',
        color:'green'
      },
      customStyleOnActiveTab:{
        color:'red'
      },
      activeTab:{
        fontSize:'16px',
        fontWeight:'600',
        color:'pink'
      }
    })
```

also, you can assign the className to the `Tab` element instead of `span` for keeping the `label` prop clean, tidy, and uniform.

Comment: Yup this is in fact what I did and was going to post this as an answer :D Anyway, I wish the `CSS` were more 'overridable' in the material UI.

Comment: :)
CSS is 'overridable' is material UI. It just takes some time to get grasp on those methods. I'm using material UI for last  6 months extensively, and I'd suggest don't ignore a single word in their documentations. :)
I'd be happy to help if you need any help in material UI thing

Answer (score 2):

You can change by use makeStyle.

```
const useStyle = makeStyles((theme) => ({
   tab: {
     "& .Mui-selected": {
      color: "red",
      fontSize: "20px"
     }
   }
})
```

then

```
<Tabs
   className={classes.tab}
>
   <Tab label="Teacher Information" />
   <Tab label="Contract" />
</Tabs>
```

Answer (score -1):

Another possible solution is to use [`withStyles`](https://material-ui.com/styles/api/#withstyles-styles-options-higher-order-component).

```js
...
import { default as MuiTab } from "@material-ui/core/Tab";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const styles = {
  // check https://material-ui.com/api/tab/#css
  // for more overridable styles

  selected: {
    fontSize: "16px",
    fontWeight: "600",
    color: "pink"
  }
};

const Tab = withStyles(styles)((props) => <MuiTab {...props} />);

function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

  const handleChange = (e, newVal) => {
    setValue(newVal);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Tabs value={value} onChange={handleChange}>
        <Tab label="Tab 1" />
        <Tab label="Tab 2" />
      </Tabs>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit falling-violet-nrh52]